# Effects Of Deorbited Space Elevator

Tags: science-fiction, space-constructs

What would happen to the earth is someone deorbited a space elevator? Let's assume it reaches up to geosynchronous orbit and the bottom is in, say, Dubia or some other part of the middle east. Furthermore its the top of the cable which has been cut and pushed out of orbit.

Comment: \**snap......woah.....crash...blammm...cries*\*

Answer (score 1):

Probably not that much, to begin with there's the fact that most designers worth their salt would include fail-safes for something like this such as parachutes along the length of the elevator. furthermore you have the issue that the most commonly suggested material for space elevators, carbon nano-tubes would burn up fairly well in the atmosphere and is also quite un-dense meaning it has a low terminal velocity.

Earth itself is definitely fine since it weighs so much compared to any proposed space elevator design. it might be a somewhat different story for the stuff on it worst case scenario you have a few dozen Chelyabinsk style events and debris lands in the desert a bunch. on a slight tangent for space elevator type stuff i'd quite advise isaac arthur's upward bound series on youtube.